Image not appearing, instead the alt value is showing
index.html code and the directory structure
output
this is my first website .
i have made a basic website which displays image of my smaller projects and a hypertext to take you to those projects.
the image was appearing when I ran it on vs-code but not when i hosted it live using github.

Probably an issue with the file path. try using devtools to see what url is being used to get the image. If you can provide minimal reproducible code or sandbox  for you code then others can debug.

i am not yet allowed to directly post image with question but i have added the link of  picture of code and the output in the starting of my question

Your Images paths are wrong
Please add these images path to display the image. It will work.
use src="./assets/images/movie-ranking.png" instead of src="/assets/images/movie-ranking.png", see mentioned code below
<img src="./assets/images/movie-ranking.png" alt="picture of my movie ranking">

<img src="./assets/images/birthday-invite.png" alt="picture of my birthday invite project">

